# ScrollView "bug" on iOS 10, swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, ios10

I have a problem with `scrollView`.
As you can see in the picture, the scrolling part ends about 50 px under the `navigationBar`, however, the `scrollView` ends right under the `navBar`

[image: iOS 10]

On iOS 11 it works how it should as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: iOS 11]

As for the constraints, here is a screenshot of them.

[image: RoundedView constraints]

Superview is scrollView and ScrollView is centered X and Y in the main View + top, bottom, left and right.

Do you know what the problem might be?
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Try to set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` on view controller.

Comment: @FahriAzimov thank you, it helped.

Comment: @GabrielBeltrameSilva thanks, didn't find this.

Answer (score 8):

Set the viewController property [automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin) to NO, by default it's YES.